# Pagina en blanco php html

Tags: php, html

Hola necesito ayuda no se porque razón al realizar el código HTML y agregándole php y al visualizarlo en Chrome, Firefox u otro navegador se ve en blanco quisiera saber si ahí algo mal dentro de mi código lo estoy haciendo en modelo vista controlador ya que estoy intentando que un producto aparezca en la pagina al agregarlo en MySQL junto con la imagen que viene desde archivos y no entiendo porque me muestra la pagina en blanco

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Estilos.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="script.js">
        <title>Purple</title>
    </head>
    <?php
          session_start();
          extract($_POST);
          require "../purple/Modelo/dataBase.php";
          require "../purple/Modelo/producto.php";
    
          if (isset($_POST['Id'])) {
    
            $objProductos = new Productos();
            $resultado = $objProducto->AgregarProducto($_POST['Id']);
    
            if (isset($resultado)) {
    
                if ($resultado->num_rows > 0) {
            ?>
    
    
       <header>
            <div class="header-content">
                <div class="logo">
                    <h1>PURPLE<b> SWEATER</b></h1>
                </div>
                <div class="menu">
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href=""><img src="img/shopping-cart.svg" alt=""></a></li>
                        </ul>    
                    </nav>
                    
                </div>
                
                <div id="ctn-icon-search">
                    <i><img src="img/search.svg" id="icon-search" alt=""></i>
                </div>
            </div>
    
        </header>
    
        <div id="ctn-bars-search">
            <input type="text" id="inputSearch" placeholder="¿Que deseas buscar?">
        </div>
    
        <ul id="box-search">
            <li><a href="#"> <i><img src="img/searchg.svg"></i> HTML</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> <i><img src="img/searchg.svg"></i> CSS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> <i><img src="img/searchg.svg"></i> JAVA</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> <i><img src="img/searchg.svg"></i> C+</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> <i><img src="img/searchg.svg"></i> C++</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> <i><img src="img/searchg.svg"></i> PHP</a></li>
        </ul>
    
        <div 
            id="cover-ctn-search" class="">
        </div>
       
    
          <!--tarjetas de productos-->
    
        <div class="body-page">        
            <div class="container-card">
               <?php foreach ($resultado as $row) { ?>
            
                <div class="card c1">
                    <div class="img">
                    <?php $id = $row['Id'];
                    $img = "../purple/img/producto/". $Id ."/Producto.jpg"?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $img; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="info-description">
                        <p><?php echo $row['Nombre']; ?></p>
                        <p>$ <?php echo $row['Precio'], 2, ".", "."; ?></p>
                        <br><input type="button" value="Agregar al carrito">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php }
    }
    }
    } 
    ?>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
```

Y aquí el modelo en donde estoy haciendo la conexión y realizando la clase

```php
<?php

class Productos extends Conecta
{
    private $Id;
    private $Nombre;
    private $Descripcion;
    private $Precio;
    private $Id_categoria;
    private $Activo;
    
    public function CrearProducto($Id = null, $Nombre = null, $Descripcion = null, $Precio = null, $Id_categoria = null, $Activo = null)
    {
        $this->Id = $Id;
        $this->Nombre = $Nombre;
        $this->Descripcion = $Descripcion;
        $this->Precio = $Precio;
        $this->Id_categoria = $Id_categoria;
        $this->Activo = $Activo;
    }

    public function setId($Id)
    {
        $this->Id = $Id;
    }
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->Id;
    }

    public function setNombre($Nombre)
    {
        $this->Nombre = $Nombre;
    }
    public function getNombre()
    {
        return $this->Nombre;
    }

    public function setDescripcion($Descripcion)
    {
        $this->Descripcion = $Descripcion;
    }
    public function getDescripcion()
    {
        return $this->Descripcion;
    }

    public function setPrecio($Precio)
    {
        $this->Precio = $Precio;
    }
    public function getPrecio()
    {
        return $this->Precio;
    }

    public function setId_categoria($Id_categoria)
    {
        $this->Id_categoria = $Id_categoria;
    }
    public function getId_categoria()
    {
        return $this->Id_categoria;
    }

    public function setActivo($Activo)
    {
        $this->Activo = $Activo;
    }
    public function getActivo()
    {
        return $this->Activo;
    }


    public function AgregarProducto()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT Id, Nombre, Precio
        FROM producto 
        WHERE Activo=1";
        $resultado = $this->getConexion()->query($sql);
        $this->getConexion()->close();
        return $resultado;
    }

}
```

Comment: el script va antes de cerrar las etiquetas html

Comment: Es probable que este dando error de PHP. ¿Tenes activado el [`error_reporting`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.error-reporting.php)? Por ejemplo, [`session_start`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.session-start) se debe ejecutar ANTES de cualquier salia. Donde esta actualmente debería estar mostrandote un error.